# Dollar Sign with \b in regex includes extra space

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to come up with a regex to match numbers which aren't prices.
100 - should match
$100 - should not match

I tried`[^\$]100` but it gets the extra space preceeding 100

[image: Regex result example]

I am trying to replace numeric words with some other string.

"100" will become "!"

This works fine, except that I want to ignore the ones that are starting with $ 
"$100" becomes "$!" 
I don't want that, I want $100 to be ignored.

Any Ideas?

Comment: so, basically you want to match the 100 part of $100?

Comment: Not really, I want to match numbers NOT starting with $.

Comment: you want a  negative look-ahead

Comment: This will do it: `^[0-9]+$`. It will match any number but nothing else. If you want it to match 100 only, just change it to `^100+$`

Comment: or match number only `[0-9]{1,}` or match the [number part of sequence that begins with `$` - like `(?<=\$)[0-9]{1,}`](https://regex101.com/r/KveDhI/1) - perhaps this is what @Dragon means. this one also possible, `(?<!\$)[0-9]{1,}`.

Comment: I think OP should clerify the question and explain what exactly it is he wants to achieve. All these comments are possibly good answers yet we can't be sure.

Comment: oooh shoot. I think I'm asking the wrong question. To provide more context, I am trying to replace numeric words with some other string. 

"100" will become "!"

This works fine, except that I want to ignore the ones that are starting with $

"$100" becomes "$!"

I don't want that, I want $100 to be ignored.

Comment: @BagusTesa something like that, but im no expert, so i was hoping some one could flesh it out `\d+` = `[0-9]{1,}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try to find numbers that are not prefixed by `$`, and replace those with that prefix character, followed by whatever you want, `!` in your example.

```
$test_string = "This is a number 100 but this isn't \$100.";
$result = preg_replace('/([^\$\d])(\d+)/', '\1!', $test_string);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You're query works like mine. 
My expected result is 
"This is a number ! but this isn't $100."
but it becomes
"This is a number! but this isn't $100."

My struggle is dollar sign's weird relationship with \b.

Comment: @KarloSerrano have you tested it with `preg_replace` including the second param? In a fiddle it works the way you want it.

Comment: @KarloSerrano maybe those are not real spaces., but as every one else says, it works: http://ideone.com/3pBley

Comment: @Jeff can you send me a linkof the fiddle. I tried it here.
https://regex101.com/r/M3cJNg/3
it still takes an extra space

Comment: @KarloSerrano your replacing the full match not the 2nd match (index 1) - see my link

Answer (score 4):

Use  a negative lookbehind with a word boundary:

```
\s*(?<!\$)\b\d+
```

Replace with `!`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3cJNg/2).

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<!\$)` - match the location not preceded with `$`
- `\b`  - a leading word boundary
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (to match a float, too, use `\d*\.?\d+`).

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/gq0UyG):

```
$str = 'This is a number 100 but this isn\'t $100.';
$re = '~\s*(?<!\$)\b\d+~';
$subst = '!';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result; 
// => This is a number! but this isn't $100.
```

Comment: Do not test PHP regex at regexr.com, that regex testing site only supports JavaScript regex flavor. Regex101.com is a much better option for testing PCRE regexps.